# Error in Javascript while trying to access element from array

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a MineSweeper program, and here's my problem:

So I make a 10x10 grid full of MineSquare objects which I defined earlier.

```
var grid = [];
    for (var i=0; i<10; i++){
        grid.push([]);
        for (var j=0; j<10; j++){
            grid[i].push(new MineSquare())
        }
    }
```

Then I make an array "bomb_list" to create 20 unique locations where the bombs will be.

```
var bomb_list = [];
var found;
var rand;
while (bomb_list.length < 20){
    found = false;
    rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
    for (var i=0; i<bomb_list.length; i++){
        if (bomb_list[i] === rand){found=true; break;}
    }
    if(!found){
        bomb_list.push(rand);
    }
}
```

Then I try to change the value of those MineSquare's to indicate they are bombs.

```
for(var x in bomb_list){
    grid[ x / 10 ][ x % 10 ].touching = -1;
}
```

I am getting an error that says "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined" which I believe is being caused when I try to take grid[x / 10].

Any reason why this is occuring?

Comment: Don't know if this is *the* cause, but I think `x / 10` should be `(x - x%10) / 10`.

Comment: others gave the answer already except that you've also misunderstood how Javascript's for works - need to do something like: `var i = bomb_list[x]` in that loop.

i made a jsfiddle where debugged & fixed this too, with that and Math.floor: https://jsfiddle.net/sg9dgpr0/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`X/10` will give you a float value, should use `Math.ceil` or `Math.floor` to get the nearest int as per your logic. Then it should work.

Comment: `Math.floor` is the right one. `x/10` to get the row is slightly to large, because x also contains the cell on that row. `Math.floor` rounds down, which is what you want in this case. B.t.w, it's `floor` and `ceil` in lowercase.

Answer (score 1):

`x/10` will produce a float. When `x` is `1`, it will be `0.1`. There is no index in `grid` of `0.1`, so the result is `undefined`. That is why you get that error.

You can `Math.floor` or `parseInt` depending on what you are trying to do:

```
for(var x in bomb_list){
    grid[ parseInt(x / 10) ][ x % 10 ].touching = -1;
}
```

Comment: `Math.floor` would be the most obvious, since it is float. `parseInt` will first convert the float to string and then try to parse that string to an int.